# VBA template Import running slow i think

Tags: excel, vba

I have put the below code together. It works perfectly but just seems to be very slow. Takes over 80 mins to import 1500 templates now maybe im expecting to much but would be great full if anyone could review to see have i done anything wrong

---

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbkSrc As Workbook
    Dim wshSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wshTrg As Worksheet
    Dim lngRow As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(4)                    ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        If .Show Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You didnt Select the import folder Dummy :)", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPath = strPath & "\"
    End If
    Set wshTrg = ActiveSheet
    lngRow = 2
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
        Set wshSrc = wbkSrc.Worksheets(1)
        wshSrc.Range("E1").Copy
        wshTrg.Range("F" & lngRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                         :=False, Transpose:=True
        wshSrc.Range("F1").Copy
        wshTrg.Range("G" & lngRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                         :=False, Transpose:=True
        wshSrc.Range("C1:C16").Copy
        wshTrg.Range("H" & lngRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                         :=False, Transpose:=True
        wshSrc.Range("F8:F16").Copy
        wshTrg.Range("X" & lngRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                         :=False, Transpose:=True
        wshSrc.Range("G8:G16").Copy
        wshTrg.Range("AG" & lngRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                          :=False, Transpose:=True
        wshSrc.Range("H8:H16").Copy
        wshTrg.Range("AP" & lngRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                                          :=False, Transpose:=True
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        wbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFile = Dir

    Loop
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should post this question in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not in SO.

Comment: The slowest part is opening the files. It can be avoided by using external references like in @paul bica's answer, or Power Query

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbkSrc As Workbook
    Dim wshSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wshTrg As Worksheet
    Dim lngRow As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(4)                    ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        If .Show Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You didnt Select the import folder Dummy :)", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPath = strPath & "\"
    End If
    Set wshTrg = ActiveSheet
    lngRow = 2
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
        Set wshSrc = wbkSrc.Worksheets(1)            
        wshTrg.Range("F" & lngRow).Value = wshSrc.Range("E1").Value
        wshTrg.Range("G" & lngRow).Value = wshSrc.Range("F1").Value          
        wshTrg.Range("H" & lngRow).Value = wshSrc.Range("C1:C16").Value 
        wshTrg.Range("X" & lngRow & ":X" & lngRow + 8).Value = wshSrc.Range("F8:F16").Value
        wshTrg.Range("AG" & lngRow & ":AG" & lngRow + 8).Value = wshSrc.Range("G8:G16").Value            
        wshTrg.Range("AP" & lngRow & ":AP" & lngRow + 8).Value = wshSrc.Range("H8:H16").Value

        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        wbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFile = Dir

    Loop
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

[The SpeadSheetGuru Timer](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/1/28/vba-calculate-macro-run-time)
My code took 7 min and 11 seconds to process 1500 8K excel files.

**Note:** Technically, this question should be moved to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

[image: SpeadSheetGuru Timer Results]

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
    Dim results As Variant

    strPath = getFileDialogDirPath

    If Len(strPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    EnableEvents False

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")

    Do While strFile <> ""
        results = getFileInfoArray(strPath & strFile)
        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            'Ron de Bruin: Find last row, column or last cell --> https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm
            LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, "E").Resize(1, UBound(results, 2)).Value = results

        End With

        strFile = Dir

    Loop

    EnableEvents True
End Sub

Private Function getFileInfoArray(FileName As String) As Variant
    With Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        With .Worksheets(1)
            getFileInfoArray = getSourceValues(.Range("E1,F1,C1:C16,F8:F16,G8:G16,H8:H16"))
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Function

Private Sub EnableEvents(TurnOn As Boolean)
    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(TurnOn, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .ScreenUpdating = TurnOn
        .DisplayStatusBar = TurnOn
        .EnableEvents = TurnOn
        .DisplayAlerts = TurnOn
    End With
End Sub

Private Function getSourceValues(Source As Range)
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Long

    ReDim results(1 To 1, 1 To Source.Cells.Count)
    For Each cell In Source.Cells
        x = x + 1
        results(1, x) = cell.Value
    Next
    getSourceValues = results
End Function

Private Function getFileDialogDirPath() As String
    Dim strPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(4)                    ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        If .Show Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You didnt Select the import folder Dummy :)", vbExclamation
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

    getFileDialogDirPath = strPath
End Function
```

I modified my original answer to use Ron de Bruin: [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) because the last cell in column E will sometimes be blank.  I also moved the code that retrieves the information from a file into `Function getFileInfoArray(FileName As String)`, in order to make debugging easier.

Comment: Thank you for the above Thomas. I have ran the above and it seems that if it opens a template and the first field it is blank which it may be in some instances it doesn't copy in any information. I cant identify where in the code above this exclusion is happening. Could you point me too it. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow processed 1,511 files (28 Kb each) in 2 min, 55 secs

Gets data from closed files, then converts formulas to values

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim srcPath As String, srcFile As String, srcWs As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, ws As Worksheet, fullName As String, t As Double

    srcPath = GetPath:  If Len(srcPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    t = Timer
    xlSpeed True
    srcFile = Dir(srcPath & "*.xls*")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    srcWs = "Sheet1"

    r = 2
    With ws
        Do While Len(srcFile) > 0
            fullName = "= '" & srcPath & "[" & srcFile & "]" & srcWs & "'!"
            .Cells(r, 5) = fullName & "E1"      'F = 6
            .Cells(r, 6) = fullName & "F1"      'G = 7
            For c = 1 To 16
                .Cells(r, c + 7) = fullName & .Cells(c, 3).Address  'C1:C16 to H+  =  8
            Next
            For c = 8 To 16
                .Cells(r, c + 16) = fullName & .Cells(c, 6).Address 'F8:F16 to X+  = 24
                .Cells(r, c + 25) = fullName & .Cells(c, 7).Address 'G8:G16 to AG+ = 33
                .Cells(r, c + 34) = fullName & .Cells(c, 8).Address 'H8:H16 to AP+ = 42
            Next
            r = r + 1:  srcFile = Dir
        Loop
        .UsedRange.Value2 = .UsedRange.Value2
    End With
    xlSpeed False
    Debug.Print "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"  'Time: 175.086 sec
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function GetPath() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(4)  'msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        If .Show Then
            GetPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(GetPath, 1) <> "\" Then GetPath = GetPath & "\"
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select the import folder", vbInformation
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Sub xlSpeed(Optional ByVal flag As Boolean = False)
    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(flag, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .ScreenUpdating = Not flag
        .DisplayStatusBar = Not flag
        .EnableEvents = Not flag
    End With
End Sub
```